# Is estimatedly a word?

Tags: word-usage

Is 'estimatedly' a word? My spell checker highlights it and Google returns only 35k results so I guess it is not, though I cannot "see" what is wrong with it.

I am using it in this context:

> According to McKinsey's 2016 report, `United States alone has more than two zettabytes (2,000 exabytes) of data' estimatedly, [...]

Comment: Regardless, you can still choose not to use it.

Comment: My meal has gone, eatenly.

Answer (score 2):

The word "estimatedly" is not in dictionaries, but you can create it according to established patterns. Whether you should use it or not will depend on what you are writing for.

It is not a totally new word: many other people have used it before. Google Books shows hits from United States Congress Senate Committee on Labor and Public Welfare, Hearings Feb. 20-Mar. 4, 1947; *Free and Easy? A Defining History of the American Film Musical Genre*, Sean Griffin, Wiley, 2017; *Population Stabilization Through District Action Plans*, Charan D. Wadhva, India, 2003; *Supplement to the Official Journal of the European Communities*. Volume 39, Issues 225–228, 1996; *Agricultural Employment Expansion: Smallholder Land and Labour Capacity Growth*, Sam Moyo, Zimbabwe, 1990, and more.

There are many similar words in dictionaries. "Allegedly" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allegedly)), "provenly" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provenly)), "demonstratedly" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demonstratedly)), "animatedly" ([OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/7780)), "affrontedly"([OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3542)), and many more, are in dictionaries, so this is a pattern that is used in other words: past participle plus "ly" to make an adverb.

You can use this pattern to create a new adverb from a past participle or adjective.

The question of what is and isn't a word doesn't have a clear answer. Many style guides will specify which dictionary to use: if it's in the dictionary, it's a word, if not, it's not a word (unless it's a proper name, foreign word, etc). For instance the [Guardian Style Guide](https://www.theguardian.com/info/series/guardian-and-observer-style-guide) refers to the Collins English Dictionary as the arbiter.

There are pros and cons to creating a new word. Often it offers a clear and efficient way of expressing a meaning. However, it may confuse people who are not native English speakers (whether they rely on translation services, get confused by something that's not in a dictionary, or don't know the rule). It may also result in an ugly red line under your word. And, as mentioned, it may fall foul of style guides that require all words to be in a specific dictionary.

Comment: Estimated and measured are typical opposites, but we don’t say “measuredly”.  New words are fine, but people infer their meaning from synonyms, antonyms and related words that have a similar form. Estimatedly doesn’t have many friends here to help it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a word actually. In your case, "**approximately**" could be the alternative you are looking for to *estimatedly* and *estimatingly*.

Answer (score 0):

> According to McKinsey's 2016 report, `United States alone has more than two zettabytes (2,000 exabytes) of data' estimatedly.

This is simply poor English. The question is irrelevant.

Try: "According to McKinsey's 2016 report, `United States alone has more than **an estimated two zettabytes** (2,000 exabytes) of data'."

Answer (score 0):

@Stuart F correctly points out that a word not being listed in latest iterations of canonical dictionaries does not necessarily constitute it as being non-existent or false.
However, I suggest to consider '**estimately**' in accordance with the construction of words with a similar suffixes such as

- immediate(ly)
- approximate(ly)
- accurate(ly)

It also yields more than twice the amount of Google-results since you brought up that (IMO perfectly valid) argument.

Whether you *should* use non- or not-yet-well-established words in a scientific text is a different question. I personally would avoid this by re-phrasing the sentence (e.g. "McKinsey's 2016 report estimates...").